# How to generate the labels of custom data for YOLO

Tags: object-detection, yolo

The labels for YOLO is like `[class, x , y, width, height]` . Since the dataset is very large, is there any shortcut to generate the labels for YOLO, or we have to hardcode them through measurement?

Comment: You can use labeling tool to generate label or a pretrained model if available to auto label.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Using Pre-trained YOLOv4 models.**
YOLOv4 models were pre-trained on COCO dataset. So,  if your object(s) can be found in this [list](https://gist.github.com/AruniRC/7b3dadd004da04c80198557db5da4bda), then, you can use the pre-trained weights to *pseudo-label* your object(s).

To process a list of images `data/new_train.txt` and save results of detection in Yolo training format for each image as label `<image_name>.txt`, use: `darknet.exe detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -thresh 0.25 -dont_show -save_labels < data/new_train.txt`

**Method 2: Using Other Pre-trained Models.** It's the same concept. Use other pre-trained models to detect your object (as long as they have trained their models on your object), then export/convert the labels to YOLO format.

**Method 3: Use hand-crafted feature descriptors.** Examples are shape detection, color-based detection, etc.

**Method 4: Manual labelling.** If everything else fails, do the labelling yourself or hire some data labelling services. Here's a list of [tools](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-mark-bounded-boxes-of-objects-and-create-annotation-files) that you can use if you want to label them yourself.